# Can I increase batch_size_fail_threshold to 1MB in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Can I increase "batch size fail threshold" to 1MB in Cassandra?

Comment: Batch size warning comes if your batch is more then 5Kb but you can change it.

Comment: Does it hurt if i increase the size? whats the value used in production?

Comment: It’s up to your use case and how you are using Cassandra

Answer (score 1):

```
# Fail any batch exceeding this value. 50kb (10x warn threshold) by default.
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb: 50
```

option in your cassandra.yaml to increase it, but be sure to test to make sure your actually helping and not hurting you're throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can set it to whatever size you want but it would be a bad idea.

A CQL `BATCH` is there to provide a means for atomic updates of a single partition across multiple tables. It is NOT an optimisation in the same way as batches are in traditional relational databases.

When you place multiple partitions in a CQL batch, the performance of that batch will be worse than issuing multiple separate write requests. We don't recommend it and it is bad practice. Cheers!

Comment: What if only 4 partitions are involved and atomicity is required? Is that still dangerous? I'm actually trying to get my head around this threshold warning.